# coordinate free Segre embedding

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Is there a coordinate free description of the Segre embedding ? Is there a relation between $\mathbb P(W)$, $\mathbb P(V)$ and $\mathbb P(V \oplus W)$ ? I don't find a reference for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Segre embedding is simply the projective version of the map $V \times W \to V \otimes W$.

For answer to your other question, there are two maps $i : V \to V \oplus W$ and $j : W \to V \oplus W$ which embedd $\mathbb P(V)$ in $\mathbb P(V \oplus W)$ and similarly for $\mathbb P(W)$.

I think the book of Harris, A first course in algebraic geometry, is a good reference

Comment: Are $\mathbb P(V)$ and $\mathbb P(W)$ are summands of $\mathbb P(V \oplus W)$ ?

Comment: This does not mean anything since $\mathbb P(V \oplus W)$ is not a vector space. But they embedd as projective subspaces.

Comment: Not even as sets ?

Comment: Summand is a term for vector spaces. Yes, as set they are subset, because as I said they embedd as projective subspaces.